# Распространение слова "чкаться"

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, жаргон, глаголы

Недавно решил поискать в словарях значение слова "чкаться" и выяснил, что данный глагол распространён только в Брянской области(откуда я родом) и в соседних областях, т.е. является примером слова из городского сленга.
Так ли это на самом деле? Или же данное слово просто является разговорным и используется повсеместно?

Comment: @ddbug если честно, я до вчерашнего дня думал, что так везде говорят.

Comment: У нас за Уралом никогда не слышал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**чка́ться**
*жарг., рег. (центр России)* то же, что слоняться; ходить, бродить, обычно без цели, без дела.
**[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)**

**чкаться**
ходить, бродить без цели, без дела, слоняться, шляться; передвигаться беспорядочно, в разных направлениях; околачиваться, постоянно находиться где-либо, обычно без особой надобности; возиться с чем-либо или кем-либо, заниматься утомительным, трудным, хлопотливым делом.
Регион: Калужская обл., Брянская обл., Орловская обл., Курская обл.(проникает также в Москву и область)
Статус: *регионально разговорное, в основном молодёжный жаргон.*
Фиксация в словарях: не фиксируется.
[**Lingvo.ru**](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=101515)

*Я не вижу смысла ехать, например, с Отрадного до Дмитровской и там ещё **чкаться** за трамваем* (форум, автор из Москвы).
*Я там **чкался** три часа — не знал куда себя деть* (форум, автор из Троицка,  Московская обл.).

[1. В Толковом словаре Даля есть слово  [***ЧКА***](http://enc-dic.com/dal/CHka-42448.html) , но смысл глаголов **чкать** и **чкнуть**, которые упоминаются в статье, совершенно другой.
 2. В Прибалтике, в Санкт-Петербурге(Ленинграде), в Новгороде со словом "чкаться" наша семья не сталкивалась (бабушка была 1909г.р.).]

Можно попытаться сделать вывод: *слово используется ограниченно — как по месту, так и по среде.*

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение! Никогда бы не подумал, что чкаются только в Брянской области и рядом с ней.

Answer (score 0):

У нас, в Саратовской области,  так не говорят, у нас говорят "слоняться".

Я тоже попыталась поискать в словарях. В словарях говоров его нет, у Даля - совсем другое значение - "толкаться", а вот в онлайн-словарях сказано, что это молодёжный сленг Брянской области и соседних с ней мест.Скорее всего, это так и есть.

Comment: Слоняются и в Брянской области, а вот откуда появилось это "чкаться"? Иногда "чкаться" употребляется и как "толкаться" (чкнуть кого-то в очереди), однако не менее часто в Брянской области чкаются по улице без дела.